# Display driver failure in PyQt5 under bookworm

Tags: display, qt, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I am running a PyQt5 console GUI (eglfs) application and seeing a problem under bookworm that I was not present under earlier versions of Pi OS.  I have observed this behaviour both on a Pi 2 with a DSI display and a Pi Zero 2 with a HDMI display, so it does not seem to be architecture dependent.  I have not however seen the problem on Pi4 or Pi5.  The screen will stop displaying (either freeze or go blank) and I then get the following error in the logger:

```
python[139076]: Could not queue DRM page flip on screen HDMI1 (No space left on device)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, or what I might do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

> No space left on device

...so you should check whether the storage partition on your Pi is full. You can do so using the `df -h` command in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, but there was plenty of space on all partitions.